# Encoding string into numbers separated by dashes, decoding numbers separated by dashes into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Task**: Write a program that gives the user a choice to encode or
>   decode. You will either encode letters into numbers separated by
>   dashes, or decode a series of numbers (also separated by dashes) into
>   letters.

I am learning python, and this Lab has proven extremely difficult because I don't yet know all the tools I need to make it function.  I managed to get the encode portion to work, but my decode portion is crap.  I think it is taking 2-digit numbers and treating them like individual numbers ("19" as "1" and "9", so returns "ai" instead of 's').  I have thought about switching from using indexing to trying to convert the numbers to letters using chr(), but not being familiar with that either, I keep getting type errors when trying to add 96 to get the correct number.
Then encode_letters function is a bit clumsy, but it works.  However, the decode_numbers function is what is giving me fits.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
def encode_letters():
    global code_out
    encryption_key = (('a','1'), ('b','2'), ('c','3'), ('d','4'), ('e','5'), ('f','6'), ('g', '7'), ('h','8'), ('i','9'), ('j','10'), ('k','11'), ('l','12'),
        ('m','13'), ('n','14'), ('o','15'), ('p','16'), ('q','17'), ('r','18'), ('s','19'), ('t','20'), ('u','21'), ('v','22'), ('w','23'), ('x','24'),
        ('y','25'), ('z','26'))
    msg_in = str(input("Enter the message you wish to encode:\n"))
    msg_in = msg_in.lower()
    from_index = 0
    to_index = 1
    for i in msg_in:
        letter_found = False
        for e in encryption_key:
            if ('a' <= i and i <= 'z') and i == e[from_index]:
                code_out = code_out + e[to_index] + "-"
                letter_found = True
        if not letter_found:
            code_out = code_out + i

    return code_out

def return_encoded():
    global code_out
    code_out = code_out.rstrip("-")
    print("Your secret code is:", code_out.replace('- ', ' '))

def decode_numbers():
    global string_out
    encryption_key = (('a','1'), ('b','2'), ('c','3'), ('d','4'), ('e','5'), ('f','6'), ('g','7'), ('h','8'), ('i','9'), ('j','10'), ('k','11'), ('l','12'),
        ('m','13'), ('n','14'), ('o','15'), ('p','16'), ('q','17'), ('r','18'), ('s','19'), ('t','20'), ('u','21'), ('v','22'), ('w','23'), ('x','24'),
        ('y','25'), ('z','26'))
    numbers_in = input("Enter the numbers separated by dashes that you wish to decode: ")
    numbers_in = numbers_in.replace('-', ' ')
    print(numbers_in)
    from_index = 1
    to_index = 0

    for i in numbers_in:
        number_found = False
        for e in encryption_key:
            if i == e[from_index]:
                string_out = string_out + e[to_index]
                number_found = True
        if not number_found:
            string_out = string_out + i
    return string_out

def return_decoded():
    global string_out
    print("Your decoded string is: ", string_out.capitalize())
```

Comment: why arent you using a dictionary as lookup?

Comment: The type error you are getting is likely due to the fact that you're trying to add an integer to a string. While you can do that in some languages (like JavaScript), you can't do that in Python -- in Python we need to convert an integer into a string to add it to a string. So `3 + 's'` throws an error, but `str(3) + 's'` does not.

Comment: My professor did briefly touch on dictionaries in our last class, and I thought that might be a good way to handle this.  I will look for instruction on creating and using dictionaries.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this quite a bit if you keep track of the type conversions:

```
def convert(s, method='encode'):
  if method == 'encode':
    return '-'.join([str(ord(i)) for i in s])
  elif method == 'decode':
    return ''.join([str(chr(int(i))) for i in s.split('-')])

s = 'cats on wheels'
encoded = convert(s, method='encode')
decoded = convert(encoded, method='decode')

print(encoded) # prints 99-97-116-115-32-111-110-32-119-104-101-101-108-115
print(decoded) # prints cats on wheels
```

As you said, one can use `ord` to convert a string to an integer, then use `chr` to convert an integer back into a string. This lets us flip a string into a sequence of hyphen separated integers, then flip that sequence back into the input string

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary makes encryption, decription easier. Example for ceasar chiffre:

```
d = {}
# build the encode/decode dict
for k in range(26):
    cha = chr(ord("a")+k)
    d[cha] = k
    d[cha.upper()] = k
    d[k] = cha

print(d)

def encode(word,offset):
    # dont use other things then a-zA-Z or else...
    return ''.join(d[ (d[c]+offset)%26 ] for c in word)

def decode(word,offset):
    return encode(word,-offset)

print(encode("abcdefg",1))
print(decode("abcdefg",-1))

print ( encode(decode("abrakadabrazzz",1),1) )
```

Output:

```
bcdefgh  # encode abcdefg , +1
bcdefgh  # decode abcdefg , -1
abrakadabrazzz # endoce + decode
```

The dictionary used looks like:

```
{'a': 0, 'A': 0, 0: 'a',     'b': 1, 'B': 1, 1: 'b',     'c': 2, 'C': 2, 2: 'c', 
 'd': 3, 'D': 3, 3: 'd',     'e': 4, 'E': 4, 4: 'e',     'f': 5, 'F': 5, 5: 'f', 
 'g': 6, 'G': 6, 6: 'g',     'h': 7, 'H': 7, 7: 'h',     ...,  
 'x': 23, 'X': 23, 23: 'x',  'y': 24, 'Y': 24, 24: 'y',  'z': 25, 'Z': 25, 25: 'z'}
```

essentially it maps any lowercase and uppercase letter to a number and the number back to the lowercase character.

The encoding `d[ (d[c]+offset)%26 ]`  looks up the "number" that belongs to a character, adds the offset, uses modulo 26 to convert `z+1` to `a` instead of an error. Then is looks up the correct "new" character by it's number.

You can do the same for your task - you just need the mapping for `character` to `number` and for `number` to `character`.

When decoding split your string at `'-'` and get the character for the numbervalue you got - when encoding go over all characters of your word  and get the correct number from a dict, then `'-'.join()` them.

---

Applied to your task:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as low  # "abc..xyz"

d = {}
number_for_a = ord("a") 
# add the letters/numbers - upper case are 100 + lower case number
for k in low:
    d[k]         = str(ord(k) - number_for_a)       
    d[k.upper()] = str(100 + ord(k) - number_for_a)  
# add the reverse mapping number to character
for k,v in list(d.items()):
    d[v] = k

def encode(word):    
    # word for both cases - if no `-` in word its iterated character wise, else
    # the word is split at '-' and any splits are put through the dictionary 
    if '-' in word:
        return '-'.join(d[c] for c in word.split("-"))
    return '-'.join(d[c] for c in word)

def decode(phrase):
    return encode(phrase)

print(encode("abcdefg"))
print(decode("1-2-3-4-5-101-100-103-104-105"))
```

Output:

```
0-1-2-3-4-5-6
b-c-d-e-f-B-A-D-E-F
```